# re-run javascript when redux router change state

Tags: javascript, redux

I use a javascript API library in a redux application.

The library and custom javascript code are in a separate js file I import in index.js (where I render redux router)

The first time I go on the application, the javascript is executed, but if I navigate through the application, the router change state but my js code is not re-run and I have to manually refresh the page

How can I manage that the script be executed at every page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe my question wasn't clear enough, sorry about this, I'm really a beginner in redux.

However I found how to resolve my problem !
First, in the router.js file, I had to import the function I want to run at every page :

```
import myFunction from './my-javascript-file';
```

And then I can tell the Router to run this function on the page I need to with the 'onEnter' parameter

```
<Route onEnter={myFunction} path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
```

I hope this would be helpful if someone has the same issue !